# Change color of like button using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an app with a list of posts and a user can like/unlike a post. For the like functionality I've used SignalR and everything works fine, but I want to change the color of the like button if the logged user has already liked a post, so that he knows which posts he has liked. I've tried doing it like this:
Html

```
<button id="like" (click)="liked(post)" class="btn liked mr-5">Like<em class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></em> {{post.likes.length}}</button>
```

TypeScript

```
 @Input() post: Post;
 button = document.getElementById('like')

 constructor(private postService: PostsService)

 liked(post: Post) {
    const user: User = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    const id = this.getDecodedToken(user.token).nameid;
    if(this.post.likes.includes(parseInt(id))) {
      this.button.style.color = "red"
    }
    this.postService.setLike(parseInt(id), post.id);
  }
```

This does not work. I get an error in the console saying `TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` and `this.post.likes.includes(parseInt(id))` returns false even if the current user has liked the post. From the backend I'm sending the list of likes and my Like class contains an id, a post id and a user id. This is how this.post.likes appeares in the console and basically what I want to do is to verify if the current user has the id of 18 or 5 and if he does, the like button must be red.

```
0: {id: 13, created: "0001-01-01T00:00:00", user: null, userId: 18, post: null, …}
1: {id: 1026, created: "2021-05-22T12:46:02.811552", user: null, userId: 5, post: null, …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Angular master, but for me, it seems like you're getting access to the button in a wrong way.

You should use one of these (preferably the first option)

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('like') likeButton: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.likeButton.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

or inject the document into the component like this

```
import { Inject }  from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; 

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {
   likeButton: any;

   constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document) {
      likeButton = document.getElementById('el');
   }
}
```

Comment: But even if I use the first or the second option I'm not able to apply styles anymore.